# JQGrid search functionality works if two same name column interchanges

Tags: jqgrid

am using JQGrid and enabled Search to true . everything is working fine.

scenario: there are two budget column one is for footer total and another is for column

```
    $("#BudgetGrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: JSON.parse($('#JsonData').val()),
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'BudgetId',
                hidden: true,
                classes: 'budgetid'
            },
            {
                name: 'Month',
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                name: 'MonthInWords',
                resizable: true,
                //align: 'center',
                label: 'Month',
                ignoreCase: true
            },
            {
                name: 'Budget',
                resizable: true,
                align: 'center',
                label: 'Budget',
                ignoreCase: true,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject, rowid) {
                    return '<input type="textbox" class="form-control number" id="budget" value=\"' + rowObject.Budget + '\"></input>';
                }
            }, 
            {
                name: 'Budget',
                resizable: true,
                label: 'Budget',
                ignoreCase: true,
                hidden: true,
                sorttype: 'number',
                summaryType: 'sum',
                formatter: 'integer',
                formatoptions: {
                    decimalSeparator: '.', decimalPlaces: 2, suffix: '', thousandsSeparator: ',', prefix: ''
                }
            }

            
        ],
        loadonce: true,
        pager: "#BudgetGridPager",
        viewrecords: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        rowNum: 12,
        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter:true,
        gridComplete: function () {
            var objRows = $("#BudgetGrid tbody tr");
            var objHeader = $("#BudgetGrid tbody tr td");

        if (objRows.length > 1) {
            var objFirstRowColumns = $(objRows[1]).children("td");
            for (i = 0; i < objFirstRowColumns.length; i++) {
                $(objFirstRowColumns[i]).css("width", $(objHeader[i]).css("width"));
            }
        }
        }
        , loadComplete: function (data) {
            var $grid = $('#BudgetGrid');
            //debugger;
            $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { MonthInWords: "Total" });
            $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 'Budget': ($grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'Budget', false, 'sum')).toFixed(3) }, false);
        }

    });

    $("#BudgetGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        autosearch: true,
        stringResult: false,
        searchOnEnter: false,
        defaultSearch: "cn"

    });
```

when i write hidden budget up search column search wont work
but when i write budget without hidden and next budget hidden , search works fine.

can anyone please say the reason behind it[image]

Comment: It is not possible to have two columns in jqGrid with the same names. This will bring you a lot of problems - actually the grid will behave very strange in this case. In the docs is noted that column names should be unique.

Comment: yeah, but without duplicate column how to add footer : Sum of Budget